# Fading images in and out messing up inline-block styled div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a grid of images and I want to have each of them randomly fade in and out. I have the gridview, and I also have the JS code for fading in and out of an image. But, when I implement the JS code on the grid of images, it doesn't work as expected.

When an image loads, the size of it's div is altered and the entire grid div is expanded.

Here is what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/10/

How can I fix this? Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>3x3</title>
 <!-- jQuery Reference -->
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
  <!-- Your Script -->
  <script type='text/javascript'>
$(function(){
      // Hide all images except the first within your "fade In" <div>
      $('.fadein img:gt(0)').hide();
      // Set an interval to occur every 3 seconds (3000ms)
      setInterval(function(){
        // Fade out the first element and fade in the next and then move the elements
        $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut()
           .next('img').fadeIn()
           .end().appendTo('.fadein');}, 
        1000);
  });
  </script>
<style type="text/css">
    #grid {
        width: 475px;
        margin: 1em auto;
    }

    #grid div { display: inline-block; width:30%; margin: 0.5em 0; padding:0; }
    #grid div p { text-align: center; margin:0; padding:0; }
    #grid div p:first-child { font-weight: bold; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="grid">
        <div class="fadein">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2597/4121218611_040cd7b3f2.jpg" style="width:100%"">
    <img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2531/4121218751_ac8bf49d5d.jpg" style="width:100%"">
  </div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
        <div><img src="http://farm3.static.flickr.com/2610/4148988872_990b6da667.jpg" style="width: 100%;"></div>
    <div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This problem is a bit trickier than it appears.  How much control do you have over your images, aspect ratio specifically.  If your images vary in size and aspect ratio, the grid structure becomes somewhat complex.

Comment: I have complete control, all images are the same size

Comment: However, you do need some responsiveness in the grid, otherwise you would have specified a width in px instead of %.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one solution to the problem.

Modify your CSS as follows:

```css
#grid {
    width: 475px;
    margin: 1em auto;
}
#grid div {
    display: inline-block;
    width:30%;
    height: 13.25vw;
    margin: 0.5em 0;
    padding:0;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    vertical-align: top;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#grid div p {
    text-align: center;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
#grid div p:first-child {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

Set a height to `#grid div` corresponding to the aspect ratio of your thumbnails.

I used `height: 13.25vw` so that the height is based on the width of the initial 
containing block (viewport), so you can maintain some responsiveness in the design.

You may need to give this some additional attention.

Finally, use `overflow: hidden`.

This construction keeps the first inline-block element to a fixed size regardless of how
many image elements are held within it.

The animation was being affected by the variable height of the inline-block that would
change depending on images being shown or hiddden (that is, display block being set to the
div).

See demo: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/6wey831p/

Otherwise, your HTML and jQuery work fine as is.

Comment: This is the best looking solution I have seen for this question

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want something like this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/11/)..

Single run:

```js
setInterval(function() {
    // Fade out the first element and fade in the next and then move the elements
    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).next('img').fadeIn(1000)
      $(this).appendTo('.fadein');
      $(this).remove();
    });
  },
  1000);
```

Multiple times [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/20/):

```js
setInterval(function() {
    // Fade out the first element and fade in the next and then move the elements

    $('.fadein :first-child').fadeOut(1000, function() {
      $(this).next('img').fadeIn(1000)
      $(".fadein").append($(this).clone());
      $(this).remove();
    });
  },
  1000);
```

Comment: This does help, but how can I make it loop back around the images after it goes through all three?

Answer (score 0):

Try using  `hide()` in `$('.fadein :first-child').hide()` instead of `fadeOut();` [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5wkcsnv5/23/)